# how to set timer to close android app

Tags: android, timer, android-music-player

I have a music app in android. 
Visit http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/
Now I need to close this app with specific time. What is technique I should use?

Thank all

Comment: Go with Handler or Timer concepts in android

Answer (score 0):

**try** `Timer concept`

```
new CountDownTimer(40000, 1000) { //40000 milli seconds is total time, 1000 milli seconds is time interval

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
  }
  public void onFinish() {
 }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use AlarmManager. 
See :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html 
[Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

On your AlarmReceiver or your AlarmService, call finish on your activity.